# Iframe transparency in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, iframe

I found on this site how to enable iframe transparency in IE, but it doesn't work for me.

I ave tried to put background transparent and allow transparency true... But the background of the frame is white. I have only a simple text in this iframe, without div backgrounds setted.

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is simple to do this:

Allowing transparency for Iframe can be done with:

```
<iframe src="" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

And with:

```
<script>
  iframe.setAttribute('allowtransparency', 'true');
</script>
```

Allow body transparency for page in iframe:

```
<body style="background-color:transparent">
```